# CKAN 2.9 ValueError: Registry initialized :: ckan basic-charts plugins

Tags: plugins, valueerror, ckan, webassets, fanstatic

I am new to ckan. After successfully installing ckan when I went to use some ckan plugins as an example ckan-basiccharts i am getting ValueError. After some research, I understand it's related to web-assets. In basicchart folder, I change the {%resource ....} to {%asset ..}

ckanext/basiccharts/theme/templates/basechart_view.html in .html file

but I am still getting the same error. Can anyone please explain the logic behind this error and some tricks to get rid of this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/../../views/resource.py", line 151, in read
    return base.render(template, extra_vars)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py", line 151, in render
    return flask_render_template(template_name, **extra_vars)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 1, in <module>
    {% ckan_extends %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 3, in <module>
    {% set res = resource %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/base.html", line 4, in <module>
    {% set dataset_type = dataset_type or pkg.type or 'dataset' %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html", line 1, in <module>
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/base.html", line 106, in <module>
    {%- block page %}{% endblock -%}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html", line 19, in <module>
    {%- block content %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html", line 22, in <module>
    {% block main_content %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html", line 53, in <module>
    {% block pre_primary %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 22, in <module>
    {% block resource %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 24, in <module>
    {% block resource_inner %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 104, in <module>
    {% block data_preview %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 105, in <module>
    {% block resource_view %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 118, in <module>
    {% block resource_view_content %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/resource_read.html", line 128, in <module>
    {% snippet 'package/snippets/resource_view.html',
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/jinja_extensions.py", line 274, in _call
    return base.render_snippet(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py", line 95, in render_snippet
    output = render(template_name, extra_vars=kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py", line 151, in render
    return flask_render_template(template_name, **extra_vars)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/snippets/resource_view.html", line 3, in <module>
    {% block resource_view %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/snippets/resource_view.html", line 27, in <module>
    {{ h.rendered_resource_view(resource_view, resource, package) }}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/helpers.py", line 2488, in rendered_resource_view
    return literal(base.render(template, extra_vars=data_dict))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py", line 151, in render
    return flask_render_template(template_name, **extra_vars)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ckanext_basiccharts-0.1-py3.8.egg/ckanext/basiccharts/theme/templates/basechart_view.html", line 1, in <module>
    {% resource 'basiccharts/main' %}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/jinja_extensions.py", line 334, in _call
    h.include_resource(args[0], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/helpers.py", line 2097, in include_resource
    import ckan.lib.fanstatic_resources as fanstatic_resources
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/fanstatic_resources.py", line 252, in <module>
    create_library('vendor', os.path.join(base_path, 'vendor'), depend_base=False)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/fanstatic_resources.py", line 243, in create_library
    registry.add(library)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fanstatic/registry.py", line 18, in add
    self[item.name] = item
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fanstatic/registry.py", line 72, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError('Registry initialized.')
ValueError: Registry initialized.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For migration to webassets, you need to create an assets folder and place there `.js` and `.css` files of the extension. In addition, you need to create webassets.yml inside the assets folder where those  `.js` and `.css` files should be registered. This process is described [here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/theming/webassets.html) and [here](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Python-3-migration-guide-for-extensions#web-assets-js-and-css).

But you can use [this](https://github.com/DataShades/ckanext-basiccharts) version of ckanext-basiccharts that is compatible with current ckan versions.